# view method calls at runtime java jar files

Tags: java, testing, methods, jar

For some testing purpose i need to find method coverage by a java application. I want to know are their any utilities to view the method calls (the name of the method called) in jar files at run time?
It will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; are you looking for something like [emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/), which is for test code coverage?

Comment: hi my goal is that while the application running i need to know which methods are being called. so that i can measure the functional coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Among others:

- http://emma.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview